# Applying the complement rule to find the number of solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 21$ with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

My Rosen's Discrete Mathematics textbook presents the following problem:

How many solutions are there to the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 21$,
where $x_i , i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$, is a nonnegative integer such
that:

$0 ≤ x_1 ≤ 3$

$1 ≤ x_2 < 4$

and

$x_3 ≥ 15$

I literally had no clue how to approach this problem, and I find it very intimidating. I don't even know where to start, honestly. I looked up the solution in the corresponding manual, but that's even more perplexing:

[image]

Could someone please help me try to make sense of this in the least complicated terms possible? How do I determine where to start and avoid making mistakes? I know this is treated like a combination problem with multisets, so the formula will involve the binomial coefficient with the top term as $n + m - 1$ and the bottom as $m - 1$, where $n$ is the number of things being picked (in this case, $21$) and $m$ is the number of variations/categories ($5$). Beyond that, I'm stumped.

Comment: If the restrictions of the problem were all $\geq0$ the problem has a well known solution. You probably know it, if not [see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). The idea is to reduce to that problem. Restrictions like $x\geq a$ for some $a>0$ can be dealt with by a change of variable $y=x-a$. The thing is that $y\geq0$ is equivalent to $x\geq a$.

Comment: The restrictions of the form $x<a$ can be treated by counting solutions of two different problems: Those in which $x\geq0$ and those in which $x\geq a$. The former we know how to solve, and the latter we saw in the previous comment how to change variable to solve it as well.

Comment: $106.{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: If $x_1\geq4$, exceptions are 5. If $x_2\geq4$, exceptions are $_5C_2+5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting it in concrete terms,
balls in bins, rather than algebraical manipulation may give you a clearer grasp.

- To start with, put $15$ balls in bin #**3**, and $1$ ball in bin #**2**. Now only $5$ balls are to be put.
- We can violate the remaining constraints only by pre-placing $4$ balls in bin #**1**$\; XOR\;$ $3$ balls in bin #**2**, and we need to subtract such arrangements.
- Putting the pieces together, ans $= \binom 9 4 - \binom 5 4 - \binom 6 4 = 106$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{0 \leq x_{1} \leq 3\,,\quad 1 \leq x_{2} < 4\,,\quad x_{3} \geq 15}$.

The answer is, $\ds{\underline{\mathsf{by\ definition}}}$, given by
\begin{align}
&\sum_{x_{1} = 0}^{3}\sum_{x_{2} = 1}^{3}\sum_{x_{3} = 15}^{\infty}
\sum_{x_{4} = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{x_{5} = 0}^{\infty}
\bracks{z^{21}}z^{x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} + x_{5}} =
\bracks{z^{21}}\sum_{x_{1} = 0}^{3}\sum_{x_{2} = 0}^{2}\sum_{x_{3} = 0}^{\infty}
\sum_{x_{4} = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{x_{5} = 0}^{\infty}
z^{x_{1} + \pars{x_{2}  + 1} + \pars{x_{3} + 15} + x_{4} + x_{5}}
\\[5mm] = &
\bracks{z^{5}}\sum_{x_{1} = 0}^{3}\sum_{x_{2} = 0}^{2}\sum_{x_{3} = 0}^{\infty}
\sum_{x_{4} = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{x_{5} = 0}^{\infty}
z^{x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} + x_{5}} =
\bracks{z^{5}}\pars{\sum_{x_{1} = 0}^{3}z^{x_{1}}}
\pars{\sum_{x_{2} = 0}^{2}z^{x_{2}}}
\pars{\sum_{x = 0}^{\infty}z^{x}}^{3}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{5}}{z^{4} - 1 \over z - 1}\,{z^{3} - 1 \over z - 1}
\pars{1 \over 1 - z}^{3} =
\bracks{z^{5}}{z^{7} - z^{4} - z^{3} + 1 \over \pars{1 - z}^{5}} =
\\[5mm] = &\
 -\bracks{z^{1}}\pars{1 - z}^{-5} - \bracks{z^{2}}\pars{1 - z}^{-5}  + \bracks{z^{5}}\pars{1 - z}^{-5}
\\[5mm] = &\
-{-5 \choose 1}\pars{-1}^{1} - {-5 \choose 2}\pars{-1}^{2} +
{-5 \choose 5}\pars{-1}^{5}
\\[5mm] = &\
-{5 \choose 1} - {6 \choose 2} + {9 \choose 5} =
-5 - 15  + 126 = \bbx{106}
\end{align}

Comment: I don't understand any of that, sorry

Comment: What do the square brackets mean? It's also not apparent in a combinatoric context what a binomial coefficient should mean with a negative argument.

Comment: @Ian $\mathbf{\left.\,1\,\right)}: \left[\,z^{n}\,\right]\mathrm{f}\left(\,z\,\right)$ denotes the coefficient of $z^{n}$ in the power expansion of $\,\mathrm{f}\left(\,z\,\right)$. Wikipedia has a [long table of mathematical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols). $\mathbf{\left.\,2\,\right)}$: Negative arguments doesn't matter at all because they are readily switched to its "positive arguments mates". Thanks for your remarks

Comment: @AleksandrH See my response to $\texttt{@Ian}$ comment.